# Return array without element at index n in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Right now I have this function:

```
function without(array, index) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    return array;
}
```

I thought this would be something lodash would have a utility for, but looks like not.

Having this function allows me to do a one-liner that I can chain:

```
var guestList = without(guests, bannedGuest).concat(moreNames);
```

No way to achieve this **without introducing a predicate** function, using lodash?

Comment: Since you already know how to do it, what's the point in a lodash solution?

Comment: We already are using lodash extensively in the project. lodash has a bunch of helper functions for Arrays. So I figured there'd be a lodash function that would allow me to accomplish the same thing as `without`, but in one line of code.

Comment: Does it have to be an index or would the value work?  lodash has several functions that takes the value rather than the index - [`without`](https://lodash.com/docs#without), [`difference`](https://lodash.com/docs#difference), and it has [`pullAt`](https://lodash.com/docs#pullAt) which does what you want but returns the *removed* values, so it can't be chained.

Answer (score 3):

[`_.without`](https://lodash.com/docs#without) already exists. Alternatively, you can use [`_.pull`](https://lodash.com/docs#pull) as well, which mutates the given argument array.

```
var guests = ['Peter', 'Lua', 'Elly', 'Scruath of the 5th sector'];
var bannedGuest = 'Scruath of the 5th sector';
var bannedGuests = ['Peter', 'Scruath of the 5th sector'];

console.debug(_.without(guests, bannedGuest )); // ["Peter", "Lua", "Elly"]
```

Banning a collection of guests is not directly supported, but we can work around that easily:

```
// banning an array of guests is not yet supported, but we can use JS apply:
var guestList = _.without.apply(null, [guests].concat(bannedGuests));
console.debug(guestList); // ["Lua", "Elly"]

// or if you are feeling fancy or just want to learn a new titbit, we can use spread:
guestList = _.spread(_.without)([guests].concat(bannedGuests));
console.debug(guestList); // ["Lua", "Elly"]
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxebe40c/3/)

Alternatively, you can look at [`_.at`](https://lodash.com/docs#at) and [`_.pullAt`](https://lodash.com/docs#pullAt) as well, which have similar behavior, except take array indexes instead of objects to remove.